# Getting code from .ipa file

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipa

Is it possible to get code from .ipa file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .ipa file has machine code, which can be disassembled into hard-to-read assembly code, but there is no way to get the original source code from the .ipa file.